# Work with WCF methods Async Call Result

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I am using Silverlight 4 with WCF Services for my database interaction . I am facing one problem.

Function all in silverlight application.

```
    ServiceReference1.WCFSLServicesClient wc = new ServiceReference1.WCFSLServicesClient();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       _wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
       wc.SayHelloCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.SayHelloCompletedEventArgs>(wc_SayHelloCompleted);

       wc.SayHelloAsync("Mr. X");
//wait untill the call finish and then move next like     

       //Here I want to do some thing with result of above call.  And then proceed to next task . 

    }

    String Name = String.Empty;
    void wc_SayHelloCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.SayHelloCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       Name =e.Result;
    }
```

But all methods calls in Silver light are Async  so I am not able to Get this out.

Comment: I also found same above in this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SyncCallInSilverlight.aspx?msg=3571404   but this uses the javascript an my app is running OOB

Answer (score 1):

Put whatever it is you want to do into another method and call that method from your Completed Handler.

```
void wc_SayHelloCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.SayHelloCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   Name =e.Result;

   MyNewMethod(Name);
}
```

Comment: maybe i'm missing something.  what is the advantage of making the call where you want instead of making it in the completed handler?

Comment: I am new to wcf could you  tell me how to call method  as non async

Comment: The short answer is you don't.  Silverlight calls services asynchronously by design.  Why do you want to?